# Problem with NSNumber (double values are off by 1)

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber

I'm getting the following output and I've no idea why!? The resulting number is off by 1.

I thought that double's can handle massive numbers? I'm sure I'm not understanding something correctly! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
(gdb) print (double) [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:9606977671929857.0] doubleValue]
$13 = 9606977671929856
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've exhausted the precision of the double-precision floating point type, which only has room for about 14 significant digits in decimal notation.

Comment: If you need more precision than this, use `NSDecimalNumber`.

Comment: Ah... right okay! So I should probably move over to unsigned long long!

Comment: @Michael `unsigned long long` is good if you only need integer precision.  If you need anything to the right of the decimal place, then it won't work.